# How can I correctly install Bochs on OSX Sierra v10.13.4?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, bochs

The path I took was using `sh .conf.macos`. After that, I tried `sudo make` and I get an error

`../bochs.h:75:12: fatal error: 'types.h' file not found`

`#include <types.h>`

using `./configure` didn't help much because when I would `make`, I get a whole bunch of errors generated from `carbon.cc`. If I understand correctly, `carbon.cc` is deprecated but how do I deal with this?

I've tried this with both Bochs 2.6.8 and the latest SVN dated April 2, 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar problems while compiling bochs on MacOs.  I saw lots of header not found problems. I tried with brew and it works.

Please use:

```
 brew install bochs
```